# Trying to add democracy precompile and getting an error that says the trait `LinearCostPrecompile` is not implemented for `DemocracyWrapper<Runtime>'

Tags: runtime, precompile

I am trying to add a precompile to my runtime(I hope this is what it is called).
What I did was import the precompile first in my runtimes's cargo.toml file. All my dependencies are fetched from polkadot-v0.9.19.

```
pallet-democracy-precompiles = { path = "../../precompiles/pallet-democracy", default-features = false }
```

In the precompile.rs file, I declared a struct and implemented some methods.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct MyChainPrecompiles<R>(PhantomData<R>);

impl<R> MyChainPrecompiles<R>
where
    R: pallet_evm::Config,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self(Default::default())
    }

    pub fn used_addresses() -> sp_std::vec::Vec<H160> {
      //fn implementation
    }
}
```

Then I implemented the PreCompileSet from pallet_evm as follows

```
impl<R> PrecompileSet for MyChainPrecompiles<R>
where
    DemocracyWrapper<R>: Precompile,
    R: pallet_evm::Config,
{
    fn execute(
        &self,
        address: H160,
        input: &[u8],
        target_gas: Option<u64>,
        context: &Context,
        is_static: bool,
    ) -> Option<PrecompileResult> {
        match address {
            // Ethereum precompiles
            // Some Non-Frontier specific nor Ethereum precompiles
            a if a == hash(2051) => Some(DemocracyWrapper::<R>::execute(
                input, target_gas, context, is_static,
            )),
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    fn is_precompile(&self, address: H160) -> bool {
        Self::used_addresses().contains(&address)
    }
}
```

In the lib.rs file did the following changes

```
pub mod precompiles;
pub use precompiles::MyChainPrecompiles;
pub type Precompiles = MyChainPrecompiles<Runtime>;
parameter_types! {
    pub PrecompilesValue: MyChainPrecompiles<Runtime> = MyChainPrecompiles::<_>::new();
}

impl pallet_evm::Config for Runtime {
    //Some types
    type PrecompilesType = MyChainPrecompiles<Self>;
    type PrecompilesValue = PrecompilesValue;
    //Some more types

}
```

When building in release mode i  am getting error as follows

```
  warning: `mychain-rpc-primitives-debug` (lib) generated 1 warning
     Compiling mychain-runtime v4.0.0 (/home/RRR/mychain-node-rr/node/runtime)
  error[E0277]: the trait bound `DemocracyWrapper<Runtime>: LinearCostPrecompile` is not satisfied
      --> /home/RRR/mychain-node-rr/node/runtime/src/lib.rs:1407:25
       |
  1407 |     type PrecompilesType = MyChainPrecompiles<Self>;
       |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `LinearCostPrecompile` is not implemented for `DemocracyWrapper<Runtime>`
       |
       = help: the following other types implement trait `LinearCostPrecompile`:
                 Curve25519Add
                 Curve25519ScalarMul
                 ECRecover
                 ECRecoverPublicKey
                 Ed25519Verify
                 Ripemd160
                 Sha3FIPS256
                 Sha3FIPS512
               and 2 others
       = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Precompile` for `DemocracyWrapper<Runtime>`
  note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `PrecompileSet` for `MyChainPrecompiles<Runtime>`
      --> /home/RRR/mychain-node-rr/node/runtime/src/precompiles.rs:32:9
       |
  32   | impl<R> PrecompileSet for MyChainPrecompiles<R>
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  note: required by a bound in `pallet_evm::Config::PrecompilesType`
      --> /home/RRR/.cargo/git/checkouts/frontier-b4643f17507d3282/7c32b14/frame/evm/src/lib.rs:127:25
       |
  127  |         type PrecompilesType: PrecompileSet;
       |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_evm::Config::PrecompilesType`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
  error: could not compile `mychain-runtime` due to previous error
```